# SSMS SQL Update statement is updating multiple databases on same server (not expected)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently deleted and restored 2 databases from a backup.  Database names are TEST01 and TEST02 on the same server.  I have verified that the database files are separate and correct.  When I run an update statement on either of the databases (database structure is identical on both), it updates data on both tables, and gives the results of both, i.e.:

```
    USE TEST01
    UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET CHANGE_DATE = GETDATE()
```

This gives the following messages.

```
    (53 row(s) affected)
    (53 row(s) affected)
```

I checked the data on both tables, and can verify that it is updating both database tables, I even tried

```
    UPDATE SERVER.TEST01.schema.TABLE_NAME SET CHANGE_DATE = GETDATE()
```

And it still updates both databases from the update statement.  Any ideas of what to look for?  There is no central server.

Comment: Are you sure the physical files (the actual data files) are different?  Sounds like yes you have two databases but both are pointing to the same physical files.  Verify by right clicking the database select properties then select the tab files.  Note the file names in each, if they are the same then you have 2 databases pointing to one physical file.

Comment: I have verified that the files are TEST01 (and TEST01_Log) and TEST02 (and TEST02_Log).  This was the first thing I looked into.

Comment: Or you have a trigger on that table.

Comment: Yes looks like a trigger to me as well based on the double message.

Comment: I have checked other tables.  They do not post the double message.  Why would the trigger update both databases without specifically calling for it?

Comment: My fault.  It was a trigger, and (all I can guess that I did was) I may have updated the wrong table, and thought I didn't, and the the trigger result had me convinced that there was a problem.  Thanks for the help.